# Express Render not working return error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm writing an Express application without a template engine I am using just using `HTML` as the template engine.

`app.set('view engine', 'html');`

actually, the whole code was generated using express-generator and I set the view to `--no-view` Flag and the index URL page runs well but trying another URL like users or any other except the index URL does work all it shows is 
`No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`
But if I Add the above code `app.set('view engine', 'html');` it returns 
`Error: Cannot find module 'html'`. Below are the codes.

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var addressRouter = require('./routes/address');

var app = express();
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/users', usersRouter);

    module.exports = app;
```

And the userRouter user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

For Home Page

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Can someone please tell what is wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean you’re just using html as the template engine? Do you mean you’re interested in serving static HTML and letting your clientside make Ajax requests?

Comment: yes paul that is what i mean

Comment: Because am using react on the client side

Answer (score 2):

To serve html you do not need to use the view engine, just use express.static, as you are already using

```
app.use (express.static (path.join (__ dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: It is still the same thing, The Same Error

Answer (score 0):

As @Henrique said, you are already able to render staticHTML. What’s tripping you up is the res.render calls.  Those specifically exist to call a template.  Switch to res.send and your error should go away.

Comment: that will return the  string `index` and not load the HTML page

Comment: I tried using `sendFile` it says the file path must be absolute

Comment: Yes, that path will just send the data you pass it. Your HTML files will be sent via their filename

Answer (score 0):

What I did was with `sendFile` on the route controller like the userRoute controller

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'../public/index.html'));
```

and I remove the set engine

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

But the index page works perfectly without the above tweak.